# "$ python -FLAG" to specify module to be loaded in Python?

Tags: python, module, pip

```
$ python minitwit_tests.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "minitwit_tests.py", line 12, in <module>
    import minitwit
  File "/.../flask/examples/minitwit/minitwit.py", line 17, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, request, session, url_for, redirect, \
ImportError: No module named flask
```

I don't have permissions to be a root so I need some flag or environment variable to specify where to load the flask

```
$ pip install -E lib Flask &> /dev/null
```

now I need to specify lib to be the dir, how to dot that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the virtualenv by running `source lib/bin/activate` in your shell.

In case `lib` is a folder you just created manually (i.e. not using `virtualenv`), delete it and recreate it as a virtualenv:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute lib
source lib/bin/activate
pip install flask
```

In case you are curious about the `virtualenv` options:

- `--no-site-packages` prevents it from using globally installed python packages. This ensures you exactly know which packages are available and have the version you need.
- `--distribute` ensures you have `pip`

Comment: Solved, thank you. Took a millisecond, 1+ million times up. I wish I could accept this answer straight a way.

Comment: [`yolk`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/yolk/0.4.3) is good to install in a virtualenv so you know what exactly is in your envrionment. You run it with `yolk -l`